# How do I get sub-segments of vector curves with consistent length?

Tags: vector, svg, raphael, bezier, curve

I am using the Raphael Javascript library to construct cubic bezier curves.  I need to get a straight segment at the very end of my curve that is a consistent length regardless the length or structure of the larger curve.  However when I place one point at the end of the curve and try to position the second 25 units back from the first, the actual distance between the points varies as I modify the curve.  Is there a way to get a straight segment at the end of my curve that is always the same length in pixels?  I am guessing this has to do with vector units being translated to actual pixels on the screen but I have found little in the way of specifics on how to remedy such inconsistencies.  Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'consistent length'. Do you mean "Take a circle of radius 25 centered at the end of the path and find the point where this circle intersects the curve", or do you mean "find the point along the swervy road defined by the curve that is 25px away from the end"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for length-along-the-path, you want to use [`getPointAtLength()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength):

```
var pt = myPath.getPointAtLength( myPath.getTotalLength() - 25 );
```

This will give you an [`SVGPoint`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGPoint) in the local space of the parent of the path.

You can see an example using this method (and more) to sample regularly along a path here:
http://phrogz.net/SVG/convert_path_to_polygon.xhtml